# Virus on linux server ubuntu server 18.04 LTS, as a remover?

Tags: 18.04, server

good afternoon!

I have a problem with my server. There is a process that is automatically renewed called "asdpouersd" and every time I kill it, it comes back with another name.

It keeps attacking all the output ports, I already blocked them all, but I wanted to remove it from the server, what is the proper procedure to remove this type of virus?

Comment: The "proper procedure" for most malware is generally to wipe all compromised partitions, clean-install a newly-downloaded release of Ubuntu, and then restore data from backups.

Comment: Can you stop it via ```sudo systemctl disable asdpouersd``` ? Or if you temporarily stop the **cron** service , does it disappear ?

Comment: when I kill in the process it is renewed, I will try this command @Parsa

Comment: Another option is to remove the file `/lib/systemd/system/asdpouersd.timer` if it exists.

Comment: dajhgiwbhf.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable dajhgiwbhf
update-rc.d: warning: disable action will have no effect on runlevel 1

Comment: @user535733 I think the first step to analyze an infected system is to gather enough information.I think he can find the exact name of the process and then search through the filesystem via ```find```.

Comment: The process:1840 root      20   0   27296   1600    400 S  36,2  0,0   4369:32 dajhgiwbhf

Comment: Haha ! This is some kind of obfuscation.An unknown program was trying to make itself permanent in the system.The name indicates it can be a malware actually.Can you search through the whole filesystem to find its files ? via **find** or so ? And looks like this might be serious because it's running as root !

Comment: Yes, I can find the files. Which file should I look for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109838/discussion-between-maicon-herverton-and-parsa-mousavi).